# c# winforms how to get MessageBoxButtons.YesNo to not disable (red)exit x

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

In the program I'm writing I've come into a bit of dilema

```
DialogResult result;

result = MessageBox.Show("question", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(result == DialogResult.Yes){
    //dosomething
}
else if(DialogResult.No){
    //dosomethingdifferent
}
```

the issue at hand is that the X becomes non-clickable, and I like that x to be clickable...
now a workaround can be found by replacing `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo` with `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCanel` but that adds a cancel button I would prefer not be there. the differences between what I want to do with no and the x are not that large, one just assures the user he pressed no rather then yes, while the other just does nothing.

so onto the question, how can I get the red x to work with just .YesNo and not have to add a cancel button

Comment: From what I can tell this is how the message box is intended to work (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546082/yesno-messagebox-not-closing-when-x-button-clicked). That in mind - if the feature is important enough you might consider spinning your own version of message box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the dialog box disables the X for YesNo because uniformity of the interface is important for a GUI. Yes/no is an exclusive choice by the user, while the X or cancel button have another semantic which cannot and should not be confused with answering no.

Comment: Oh well, guess I'll just suck it up and use that extra button there, I had sorta figured it wasn't possible, Thanks!